# How to upload/update Wordpress themes on Google App Engine without FTP?

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, ftp

I realised that, according to the Google Cloud documentation, unfortunately running wordpress on google app engines does provide any core FTP services!!

Thus if I want to update any new Wordpress themes/plugins onto my Google App Engine each time I add/remove new code, how am I supposed to update them on Google App Engine if there's no FTP service available?!

Also would the gsutil update function work?  Will it behave the same thing as I would do upload/download wordpress themes/plugin as I do use the WP Admin screen.

My only concern for the above approach is that I have my local wordpress that's pointed to this URL **localhost** thus I might worry that when I upload my local copy, this will overwrite the site url of my google app engine account!!  Is that case?  I need some confirmation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no FTP, the way you upload changes to App Engine is through the appcfg.py utility (or using the graphical launcher tool). This will update all the code in your application, including any plugins or themes you may have installed.

However it will *not* update the database, which usually means that content and settings that you have running will not change. Just the themes and modules.

Finally, App Engine has a neat feature called Versions, which allows you to run multiple copies of your Wordpress code simultaneously (they share the same database) under different URLs. Each version gets a URL like v2.myblog.appspot.com So if you update your code, do it to a seperate version, check that it works, then if you are happy with it, make it the default version. You can read more here:

https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/06/25/harnessing-the-power-of-versions-on-app-engine/

Comment: Thanks so much for that, Andrew! You have no idea how frightened it is for me to lose all the data on my application if I haven't figured a way to resolve the website url issue.  I just did the appcfg.py update  moments ago.  No reported technical issues were found!
Thank you for the link as well.  I'll think about it using as my web site gets more complex as it grows in size.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

#### First there is no FTP service in AppEngine.

1-You can use CloudStrage for upload by default plugin that is **Google Cloud Storage plugin**.

[image: plugin]

2-Enter the GCS bucket name **[YOUR_PROJECT_ID] .appspot.com** that you changed to ACL

[image]

2.5- Before 2, Change principal to **Allusers** default bucket **[YOUR_PROJECT_ID] .appspot.com**

3- If your region is correct that is CloudSQL, GCStrage,
Place your theme under **projects> wordperss > theme**  and deploy it.

[image]

You can use your theme in App Engine